# How to integrate "prefetch_related" data into queryset and serializer?

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two models with random data about Phones. The Queryset sends the Min Price Value of each phone to my API...

**models.py**

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='phone_img/', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True )
    slug_phone = models.SlugField(blank=True)

   <...>

class Price(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True) 
    phone = models.ForeignKey(Phone, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
class PhoneAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Phone.objects.annotate(min_price=Min('price__price'))
    serializer_class = PhoneSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    min_price = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        fields = '__all__'
```

Till here everything works fine, I get the min_price of each phone in
my database represented in my API.

**API Output**

```
{"count":7,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"id":10,"min_price":718,"name":"SAMSUNG Galaxy S10","description":"SAMSUNG Galaxy S10, Smartphone, 128 GB, Prism Black, Dual SIM","image":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/phone_img/galaxy_s10.jpg","slug_phone":"samsung-galaxy-s10"}, <...and so on...>
```

---

The question I have is, **how to access the object which is related to the min_price of each phone?** For instance the Price.date and or Price.market of the Phone.

So I read about "prefetch_related" and tried in my view / queryset.

**views.py**

```
class PhoneAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Phone.objects.prefetch_related('price_set').annotate(min_price=Min('price__price'))
    serializer_class = PhoneSerializer
```

So far my API did not break, but I also shows no related data. Do I need a specific field in my serializers.py do represent the data?

### Update

As dirkgroten mentioned I nested the **PriceSerializer** in the **PhoneSerializer**:

**serializers.py**

```
class PhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    min_price = serializers.IntegerField()
    sdata = PriceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        fields = '__all__'

class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = ('id', 'phone', 'price', 'date', 'market')


    phone = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    market = serializers.StringRelatedField()
```

The Output is the same as above, no new values.

**API Output**

```
{"count":7,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"id":10,"min_price":718,"name":"SAMSUNG Galaxy S10","description":"SAMSUNG Galaxy S10, Smartphone, 128 GB, Prism Black, Dual SIM","image":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/phone_img/galaxy_s10.jpg","slug_phone":"samsung-galaxy-s10"}, <...and so on..>
```

Comment: `prefetch_related` only optimises your queries, it doesn't change anything about your serialiser. You just need to add the [nested relationship](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) by adding the `PriceSerializer` in your `PhoneSerializer`

Comment: i added `codesdata = PriceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)` to `code PhoneSerializer` and also changed the fields`code fields = ('name', 'min_price', 'sdata')`. It showed me the Phone.name and the min_price value in the API but no additional data of the price.model

Comment: Update the code in your question with the changes you made.